# How to get parameters from DialogFlow in Java (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I need to get parameters from DialogFlow to my Android app.
I tried using `getQueryResult().getParameters().getFieldsMap()`
but the result is the following.

```
{type=list_value {
      values {
        string_value: "pizza"
      }
    }
    , ristorante=string_value: ""
    }
```

I would like to get just the string value "pizza" and not the entire FieldMap.
I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248301/java-how-to-extract-parameters-from-google-dialogflow-v2-response) topic, but it didn't help me, because I don't know what protobuf is and seems a bit complicated.

Is there a simple way to get a parameter's value?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1. Try to access the Map values directly.

The [`getFieldsMap()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Struct.html#getFieldsMap--) method returns a java.util.Map class. You can try to retrieve the values by getting first a [collection of Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--), then iterate:

```
Collection colletion = <Detect_Intent_Object>.getQueryResult().getParameters().getFieldsMap().values():
for (iterable_type iterable_element : collection)
```

From my humble point of view the bucle is necesary because there could be more than one parameter.

2. Transform the protobuf response into a json and access the values.

Sample code:

```
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;
String jsonString = JsonFormat.printToString(<Detect_Intent_Object>.getQueryResult().getParameters());
// Then use a json parser to obtain the values
import org.json.*;
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonnames = obj.names();
```

Method `names()` will let you know the string [names](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) you want to access.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i've already to use "printToString" method, but i get "Cannot resolve method 'printToString' in 'JsonFormat". Obviously i've imported com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;
Maybe these options in gradle file are useful for you to understand why:
`android {
  compileSdkVersion 30
  buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }`

Comment: I'm not quite sure if the jar/package that includes the class `com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat` can be a different one because as far as I can see `printToString` is documented in other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44653021/9457843). Can you try either 1) Using `JsonFormat.printer().print(<MessageOrBuilder(Intent_Parameters)>)` or 2) Or this another class to check if `printToString` is available: `com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat.printToString(<Intent_Parameters>)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dialogflowv2

```
public String getParameter(GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookRequest request, String parameterName) {
  try {
        GoogleCloudDialogflowV2QueryResult queryResult = request.getQueryResult();
        Map<String, Object> parameters = queryResult.getParameters();
        String parameter = (String) parameters.get(parameterName);
        if(parameter != null && !parameter.equals("")) {
            return parameter;
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException  e) {
            logger.error("Error");
        }
    return null;
}
```

If you use GoogleActions

```
public String getParameter(ActionRequest request, String parameterName) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> parameters =  request.getWebhookRequest().getQueryResult().getParameters();
            String parameter = (String) parameters.get(parameterName);
            if(parameter != null && !parameter.equals("")) {
                return parameter;
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException  e) {
            logger.error("Error");
        }
        return null;
    }
```